# Spring data repository with kotlin - sugestions in Intelij

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data

When I was using Java + Spring Data and type "find" as function name in interface which extends `JpaRepository`, Intelij Ultimate suggests next words.

It doesn't with Kotlin. Have you any advices?

Comment: Try to restart IntelliJ for me it works by default.

Comment: I tried of course. I think, the reason is that I'm using kotlin. But maybe there is a plugin for intelij or something

Comment: For sure that's not a reason. I'm also using Kotlin and Spring data. Please, check if you have Spring data plugin installed. I have IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.1 (Ultimate Edition) and everything works correctly.